# Firing animation function only on initial load

Tags: jquery, animation, cookies

I have a website (`http://scott.rtcgraphics.com`) that runs an animation when the user first logs on to the home page.  I would like to set some kind of conditional logic so that the function that triggers this animation is only fired the first time a person views the site.  I have been trying got do this with cookies, but the whole concept is very new to me.  As of now, the animation still fires every time I go back to the home screen.  Any guidance would be very much appreciated!  My code is below:

```
    var cookie;
    function openingAnimation(){
        // Set cookie for openingAnimation();
        document.cookie="animation=played";
        cookie = document.cookie;
        console.log(cookie);

        ...do animation...
    };
    if (cookie == null) {
        openingAnimation();
    }
```

Comment: Why not use a session flag, if it's not set include the Javascript include for the animation, if it is skip including it? You should be able to control it fairly easily from the server. Another alternative is to use a browser-based session, although you would need to check browser compatibility and it would perhaps be trickier to manage when the login occurred and the flag needs to be reset.

Comment: Hi Jared!  Could you please provide an example of the syntax for a session flag?  Thank you!

Comment: Since I have no idea what server language you're using, that would be difficult. However you use sessions on your server, simply add a check for this flag in your page template to include or not include according to what I wrote above. It's pretty basic programming technique.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, do something like this within your page template... (Assuming you've already initiated sessions and whatnot.)

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['show_initial_home_animation'])) {
    $_SESSION['show_initial_home_animation'] = true;

    echo "<script>window.addEventListener('load', openingAnimation);</script>";
}

?>
```